# Blazor set parameter on FluentButton onClick event

Tags: c#, parameters, onclick, blazor, fluent-ui

I am trying to set the R_Id parameter on the FluentButton Navigate method, but the reference does not exist in current context. I am new to C# and have spent hours on this to no avail.

The data populates the grid fine, its just getting that paramater set on the onClick event that is the problem.

I did try to adjust the Items to AsEnumerable, that fixed the error on the click but created a new CS0411 error on the DataGrid.

```
     <FluentDataGrid Items="@sccRequests" Pagination="@pagination">
  <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.R_id)" Sortable="true" />
  <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.frmwhen)" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" Sortable="true" />
  <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.SKU)" Sortable="true" />
  <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.related)"  Sortable="true" />
  <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.status)" Sortable="true" />
  <TemplateColumn Title="Actions" Align="@Align.End">
           <FluentButton IconEnd="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.Edit())" @onclick="@(e => Navigate(R_id))" />
      </TemplateColumn>
```

code:

```
    public IQueryable<RequestModel>? sccRequests { get; set; }


public async Task RefreshReadData()
{
   sccName = userModel?.userEmail;
   sccRequests = null;
   sccRequests = (await sql.GetRequestsByScc(sccName)).AsQueryable();
    
}
```

Comment: Always post code (and error messages) as text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template column is a ["templated component"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0).

Inside you can access the item with `context.` .

```
<FluentButton @onclick="() => Navigate(context.R_Id)" ... />
```